# Calculating distances across land only

Tags: qgis

I am trying to do point to point distances in QGIS but I have points to point distances that are being calculated across oceans.

Given people don't generally fly around cities does anyone know a way I can calculate the distance between points but restricted to land routes only (preferably roads would be great but that'd be an added luxury)?

Answer (score 1):

Given a fairly detailed road network is available, the shortest distance can be calculated using the Network Analysis plugin in QGIS.

This [tutorial](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html) should help.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. Unfortunately for some reason I can't download pluggins at work (must be firewalled somehow). I'll try on the weekend and let you know.

Comment: You could download the plugin at home and then manually add it at work.

Comment: Generally at work internet is provided through a proxy server. You could try adding proxy details in Settings - Options - Network. Else as @BritishSteel said, download & copy the plugin at home and paste it at work in the "C:\Users\<username>\.qgis2\python\plugins\" directory (for Windows).

Comment: Hi again, I have taken a look at the Road Graph pluggin. It seems like it can only generate the shortest route for one point to point query at a time. I need to calculate the distance from various points in a city to a central point location. Does anyone know if this can be done? I have about 50,000 starting points so doing them one by one isn't an option.

Comment: I am not sure there is currently a mechanism to automate Road Graph to run on multiple destinations at the same time. If straight line distance will suffice you can refer to this tutorial - http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html